# How do I open the javascript console in Safari 6?

Tags: development, safari, javascript

I just got a new Mac and it comes with Safari 6 installed. I've opened up the Safari 6 web inspector tools and now I can't find some of the tools I used before in Safari 5.

In Safari 5 you can press `esc` and have the console pop up and type in javascript. In Safari 6 I can't find it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it separately. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: I'd disagree and your answer has made it more clear that the two questions are so inter-related as to be pretty much one thing. The other question was how do I debug a js file? It seems that you do that by selecting the js in the files list and simply adding breakpoints etc. So the real answer to my question is to select a js file in the file list and drag the quick console to make it bigger. Then you can do as before, and `esc` will get you into the quick console.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The console still exists, but it has moved.

Click the speech bubble tab at the top of the sidebar on the left side of the screen and then click on the `Current Log` entry in the sidebar.

[image]

The keyboard shortcut to jump to this tab is <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>opt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

Note that the quick console is always available at the bottom of the screen and can be enlarged by dragging its top border upwards.

I recommend giving the [About Safari Web Inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH1-SW1x) a good read to familiarize yourself with the new Dev Tools.

Comment: sorry for asking a question but cmd+opt+c is not really working for me...
*is there any other way?*

Answer (score 25):

Open Safari and choose Safari > Preferences > Advanced. Then select the checkbox 'Show Develop menu' in menu bar.

Choose Develop > Show Error Console.

Answer (score 0):

In Safari 10, how to get to the console a few ways:

right click "anywhere on the web page" -> "inspect" and the dev tools open up.

right click on toolbar (or "view" menu) -> customize toolbar, then add "inspect element" button.  When you subsequently use it, it pops up the standard dev tools.

Comment: It is worth to mention that the `inspect` option in the context menu only appears if the main menu of development is enabled (as comments @Evangelin)